# Importing Shapefile to File GDB with domains and coded values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, domains

If I have a shapefile with attributes and values that I need. What happens when I import it into a GDB with domains for that attribute? Say in my shapefile I have a feature with attribute 'TYPE' with a value of 'HOME' and import it into the GDB the value is 'HOUSE', does it convert my value 'HOME' to 'HOUSE' to maintain consistency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it does not. Shapefiles do not support domains.
When you import this into a GDB, the process does not automatically assign domains, even if the field names are the same.
You will need to manually assign a domain to the field (Either an existing domain or a new domain)
To conform to your existing domain you will need to modify the values in the feature class manually as well

Comment: This makes sense.

Comment: +1 Moreover what looks like "HOME" in database is most likely short integer, e.g.2. This is one of the reason of domain invention

Answer (score 1):

The domains transfer over as well into your GDB, you may need to re-assign them